# Unexpected ... Unexpected token exception when writing Crystal JSON converter

Tags: crystal-lang

Why does usage of this JSON converter/parser *always* result in an exception (`Unexpected token: EOF at 1:98`)?

```
class MyParser
  def self.from_json(value : JSON::PullParser) : String
    "static"
  end
  # ...
end

class User
  JSON.mapping(
    first_name: {type: String, converter: MyParser},
    last_name: {type: String, converter: MyParser}
  )
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage of `JSON::PullParser` always requires you to consume one entire value. If you don't want to read a json value, you can use `JSON::PullParser#skip`.

To visualize why this is, consider a `JSON::PullParser` as a cursor into the JSON stream. When the `from_json` method gets called, the cursor is positioned in the stream like `"key": |"value"` where `|` is the cursor position (obviously `"value"` can be an array, another object, or anything). If you read the string by calling `read_string` on the `PullParser`, you get to `"key": "value"|` and the cursor is ready to read a `,` then the next object key, or `}` if it's the end of the object. If you don't want to read the value you must call `skip` to reach the same state as if you'd called `read_string`, or the parser will be in an invalid state.

Comment: Thanks. That's a bit surprising, but good to know. I'll need to dig a little deeper to understand how/why that works the way it does.

Comment: It's because the pull parser is positioned at the thing you want to consume. It can be an array, it can be an entire object. You need to tell, in `from_json`, what are you consuming to produce a given value. But probably a "static" value doesn't make much sense... now sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: @pdoherty926 Consider it in terms of a cursor into the JSON stream. When the `from_json` method gets called, the cursor is like `"key": |"value"` where `|` is the cursor (obviously `"value"` can be an array, another object, or anything). If you read the string by calling `read_string` on the `PullParser`, you get to `"key": "value"|` and the cursor is ready to read `,` then the next key, or `}` if it's the end of the object. If you don't want to read the value you must call `skip` to reach the same state as if you'd called `read_string`, or the parser will be in an invalid state.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, those comments are enlightening. @asterite, this example is contrived. I was just trying to get a proof of concept working and thought if I respected the method's type signature, everything would work as expected.